# New head unit in old Renault Clio (96)

Tags: audio

I'm trying to fit a brand new head unit (`Pioneer MVH-X580DAB`) into my Renault Clio, 1996 model.

The old head unit is called a `Philips DC 208` and has a single 10-pin input like this (*exhibit A*):

[image: Exhibit A: 8pin]

which connected via this crazy-looking thing (*exhibit B*):

[image: Exhibit B: crazy looking thing]

into the car itself which has two 8-pin adaptors like this (*exhibit C*):

[image: Exhibit C: the adaptors coming out of the car]
*(Note: I unfortunately didn't think to check which of B connected to which of C before I disconnected them!)*

The stereo I have (which I guess is fairly standard) has this pair of 8-pin adaptors (*Exhibit D*):

[image: Exhibit D: new stereo's adaptors]

So the temptation is to just put the two 8-pin adaptors directly into the car, by-passing *Exhibit B* altogether. But I'd like some reassurance that this is a sensible thing to do.

Can anyone shed light on what any of these wires are and how to hook the stereo up to my car?

Comment: OK, I'm starting to think that what is coming out of the car (C) is a standard [ISO 10487](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectors_for_car_audio) and that what's coming out of the stereo (D) is too. So it *should* just work. Right?

Comment: Yes! It works. In fact it's cleverer than I realised. You *can't* plug the wrong thing into the wrong thing because the two 8-pin connectors are differently shaped.

Comment: Ha! It's awesome when you figure out your own issue, eh? Please write it up in an answer and select it as such :-) Welcome to Mechanics.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straightforward operation, assisted by the design of the connectors ([ISO 10487](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectors_for_car_audio)).

You actually *can't* plug either of these 8-pin adaptors into the wrong thing because the design of the adaptors.

If you look at the connectors end-on, you'll see that the [shape of the plastic housing is different](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AISO_10487_connector_pinout.svg). Each has an alignment tab sticking out of one side, but one of these tabs is a little off-centre.

Just plug the connector into whichever housing will fit and you're good to go. This is literally impossible to get wrong.